# firebase firestore Node js how to create admin page

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want my website to have an admin page from where ONLY I can access the firestore db and do different reads and writes.

Currently in my project I am using Cloud Functions but I do not understand how I can set it so that only one user ( me ) can access some of the cloud functions from index.js.

It currently looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getProfile = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  ...  
  }
```

getProfile should be a cloud function accessible to anybody but other than this I'd like to have other read / write functions only accessible by one user , the admin , me.

Should I create another project for the admin side? which would have its own index.js for cloud functions?

Comment: are you building your website by using some interconnected cloud functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where ONLY I can access the firestore db

1. Write the firebase cloud firestore rules as follow:

   allow read: if request.auth.uid == "your-user-uid";
   allow write: if request.auth.uid == "your-user-uid";

> only one user ( me ) can access some of the cloud functions from index.js.

> getProfile should be a cloud function accessible to anybody

These are contradicting but I am guessing you are allowing only ONE cloud function accessible to the public and everything else only accessible to you. You can use the context argument in the cloud function to access the request's user uid like so and restrict access:

```
if (context.auth.uid === "your-user-uid"){
    runFunction();
    return {
        error: false,
        msg: "Function run was successful."
    }
}
else{
    return {
        error: true,
        msg: "You do not have admin privilege to access this cloud function."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set firestore rules in the firebase console and reference some specific information which will only be accessible by you.

Creating a new firebase project isn't the best solution.

For Example
In firestore you can set rules to only allow specific data to be read and written by the user. While you can allow read and write by the admin.

Once you set up a firebase auth user you get a uid, this can be used reference the admin in the firestore rule